# How to consume web service from an applet using cxf framework?

Tags: java, web-services, applet, cxf

I´m a newbie using java and cxf framework

I´m trying to consume a web service from an applet. I create the web service client using eclipse and web service client wizard. When I run the applet from the IDE it works, but when I run the applet from the browser it doesn´t. I deploy the jar using the option export Runnable JAR file. The Error that I get is java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\testingWS\META-INF\cxf\org.apache.cxf.JDKBugHacks.all

I have been googling and what I found was this cxf/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/common/logging/JDKBugHacks.java but nothing about org.apache.cxf.JDKBugHacks.all

Thanks in advance